# Virtual Java1.6 detected while trying to acces Java 1.8 physical files

Tags: java, appv

My machine has Java 1.8 physical application installed and Java 1.6 virtual application installed.When shortcut related to JAva 1.8 is launched its taking java 1.6 virtual files and it fails.

This is the code I observed when I selected "detail" tab when shortcut is failed

Also, The application works fine when only physical 1.8 is installed but fails when virtual 1.6 is also installed in same machine

The Java version that will be used to launch the product. -->

```
<!-- Java version ranges are listed in preferred order from first to last. --> 
<!-- The client system will be checked for all version ranges, in the listed order. --> 
<!-- If the client system does not have any JVMs installed that match the listed    -->
<!-- version ranges, Webstart will download the newest available version permitted  -->
<!-- by all of the version ranges taken together, regardless of order. -->
<!-- So: when the j2se version is set to "1.7*"... -->
<!--   1) Webstart will first check the client system for Java 1.7.   --> 
<!--      1.7*      = version starts with 1.7           --> 
<!--   2) If a valid update level of Java 1.7 is not found, Webstart will download    -->
<!--      the newest available version permitted by any of the version ranges.        -->
<!--      So, as of this writing, Webstart would download 1.7 update 25 at this step. -->
<!--      As later updates of 1.7 are released, Webstart will download those instead. -->
<!--      It will never download Java 1.8 since the version range does not permit it. -->
<!-- CA Wily has deliberately chosen 1.7.0 as the minimum update level since this  -->
<!-- we assume Java 7 features are available.                   -->
<!-- Users can customize the ranges to allow other update levels at their own risk.   -->
<!-- If you edit the below version range list, be sure to edit the following file as well -->
<!-- to use an identical list: com.wily.introscope.workstation.feature_#.#.#.jsp, located -->
<!-- in the same directory as this file. --> `      
<j2se version="1.7* 1.8*" 
      java-vm-args="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true" 
      href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
<property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
```

```
<!--  <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">-->
  <application-desc main-class="com.ca.apm.introscope.workstation.webstart.launcher.LaunchWrapper">

    <argument>-noexit</argument>
    <argument>-clean</argument>

    <argument>-loginhost</argument>
    <argument>30.130.37.38</argument>
    <argument>-loginport</argument>
    <argument>5001</argument>
    <argument>-autofill</argument>
    <argument>true</argument>
    <argument>-timezone</argument>
    <argument>timezone</argument>


    <argument>-conmeth</argument>

<argument>all</argument>


  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: What is a _"Java 1.6 virtual application"_?

Comment: Java 1.6 is an appv package which is created virtually

Answer (score 0):

Your AppV JRE might be leaking. This can happen when the deployment.properties file in the AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment does not get captured during sequencing and the native JRE begins reading from that file.
Refer to http://packageology.com/2014/02/sequencing-java-the-definitive-guide-part-1/
for the complete sequencing guide.